# Exporting functions from inside fetch.then

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a fetch in my code to take a csv file, convert the data to an array and then i have multiple functions inside of my .then using that array.

Now i wrote some unit tests using Jest in another file and I want to export the functions inside my .then so they can be tested. The code is as follows:

```
    fetch('./public/documents/afkoopgrenzen.csv')
    .then((e) => {
        function calc(year) {
            if (1994 < year && year <= 2018){
                let result =  
                    data.filter(function(data) {
                        return data.Jaar == year
                    })
                return result[0]["Wettelijke afkoopgrens"]
            } else {
                return 0            
            }
        }
        module.exports = calc
     })
```

Then in my script.test.js file I try to run it using

```
const tester = require('./script')
```

and then i run my tests, I know the tests work on their own but now they just say calc is not a function, because apparently module.exports = calc doesn't work when its being done in the .then scope. I can't take my function out of the then scope and see no other way to export the function to my test file.
I hope this makes sense to anyone.

Let me summarize: I need to export my function from the .then scope to be used in another .js file.

Comment: You cannot asynchronously export. The module is executed just once through and exports collected. It makes no sense to wait for an export from another module

Comment: Why can't you dedine function calc outside of then?

Comment: What is `fetch`? Does this run in a client-side or server-side environment?

Comment: @Bergi It's https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch I would imagine.

Comment: Btw, why are you even calling `fetch()` if you are not using its result `e` anywhere?

Comment: "Why can't you dedine function calc outside of then? – "
if i try to write the function out of the scope i cant use the result 'e', it always returns undefined.

"Btw, why are you even calling fetch() if you are not using its result e anywhere? "
This is not the whole function, I do use e, but it doens't really matter for my question what the actual function is about

" It makes no sense to wait for an export from another module "
it does make sense in this case, since im trying to unit test it